# Mysql left join take too much time

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

Can anyone help me to know why is my query take too much time to excute.
I have 2 table, transaction_log and purchasing_receipt.

Here is the DDL:

```
-- payment.purchasing_receipt definition

CREATE TABLE `purchasing_receipt` (
  `purchasing_receipt_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Purchasing Receipt Id',
  `processing_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Processing Id',
  `merchant_no` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Merchant Number',
  `receipt_no` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Receipt No',
  `ext_store_cd` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'External Store Code',
  `total_amount` decimal(12,0) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Amount',
  `purchasing_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Purchasing Date',
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created Date',
  `created_by` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created By',
  `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Updated Date',
  `updated_by` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Updated By',
  `ext_store_name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'External Store Name',
  `pos_number` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'POS Number',
  `management_no` varchar(89) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Management Number',
  PRIMARY KEY (`purchasing_receipt_id`),
  KEY `purchasing_receipt_processing_idx` (`processing_id`),
  KEY `ix_batch_p` (`processing_id`,`purchasing_date`,`total_amount`,`ext_store_cd`,`merchant_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `purchasing_receipt_processing` FOREIGN KEY (`processing_id`) REFERENCES `batch_processing` (`processing_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2019121320000000015 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Purchasing Receipt';
```

and:

```
-- payment.transaction_log definition

CREATE TABLE `transaction_log` (
  `transaction_id` char(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Transaction Id',
  `transaction_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Transaction Date',
  `transaction_status` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Transaction Status',
  `transaction_amount` decimal(8,0) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Transaction Amount',
  `consumer_user_profile_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Consumer User Profile Id',
  `consumer_pay_profile_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Consumer Pay Profile Id',
  `merchant_no` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Merchant Number',
  `merchant_name_kanji` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Merchant Name Kanji',
  `merchant_name_kana` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Merchant Name Kana',
  `affiliated_store_no` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Affiliated Store Number',
  `affiliated_store_name_kanji` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Affiliated Store Name Kanji',
  `affiliated_store_name_kana` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Affiliated Store Name Kana',
  `terminal_no` varchar(13) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Terminal Number',
  `cancelled_flag` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Cancelled Flag',
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created Date',
  `created_by` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created By',
  `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Updated Date',
  `updated_by` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Updated By',
  `matched_flag` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `report_year_month` char(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_user_id` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `merchant_pay_name` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `installed_store_no` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Installed Store Number',
  `installed_store_name_kanji` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `installed_store_name_kana` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `usage_item_flag` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `processing_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `transaction_log_sequence_idx` (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `con_idx` (`consumer_user_profile_id`),
  KEY `con_idx1` (`consumer_pay_profile_id`),
  KEY `FK_idx` (`terminal_no`),
  KEY `FK_idx1` (`processing_id`),
  KEY `optimize_batch_t` (`transaction_id`,`transaction_date`,`transaction_amount`,`installed_store_no`,`merchant_no`,`matched_flag`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_con_pay` FOREIGN KEY (`consumer_pay_profile_id`) REFERENCES `consumer_pay_profile` (`consumer_pay_profile_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_con_user` FOREIGN KEY (`consumer_user_profile_id`) REFERENCES `consumer_user_profile` (`consumer_user_profile_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_process` FOREIGN KEY (`processing_id`) REFERENCES `batch_processing` (`processing_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_terminal` FOREIGN KEY (`terminal_no`) REFERENCES `pos_terminal_profile` (`terminal_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tran_sequence` FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_id`) REFERENCES `transaction_id_sequence` (`transaction_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Transaction Log';
```

I've indexed the column for two table:

```
CREATE INDEX optimize_batch_t
ON transaction_log(transaction_date, transaction_amount, merchant_no, matched_flag, processing_id);

CREATE INDEX ix_batch_p
ON purchasing_receipt(purchasing_date, total_amount, merchant_no, processing_id);
```

And here is the query:

```
SELECT p.purchasing_receipt_id
            , CASE WHEN count(t.transaction_id) = 1 THEN min(t.transaction_id) ELSE NULL END 
            , CASE WHEN count(t.transaction_id) = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'U' END 
FROM purchasing_receipt p 
LEFT JOIN transaction_log t 
            ON t.transaction_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(p.purchasing_date, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) AND DATE_ADD(p.purchasing_date, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) 
            AND t.transaction_amount = p.total_amount 
            AND p.merchant_no = t.merchant_no 
            AND t.matched_flag = 'N' 
WHERE p.processing_id = 783 GROUP BY p.purchasing_receipt_id ;
```

I've check and it show that the query use correct index.
[image]
The transaction_log table has 261690 record. And Purchasing_receipt has 100063 record.
And the query take 128 minutes to complete.

I've stucked with this issue a few days and still dont understand why the query execute is too slow like that.

Comment: To debug these queries. I suggect you start breaking them down into the simple queries and timing them. Think of it as writing a 'pipeline' of queries. Trace and time them. I suggest that you may decide for a different 'driving' table. Also, indexes can add a lot overhead if you are selecting many rows from a table. Tuning queries is interesting as you  may know more about the data structures and access than the database engine does. That is what 'hints' are for,

Comment: Learn the basics of relational & SQL optimization/implementation/performance by query engines in general via textbooks & the web & SO & in particular via DBMS manual--all immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. Appropriate research is expected for questions. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS A [mre] includes code initializing data. PS Use text, not images/links, for what can be given as text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by making sure to use the same `COLLATION` in `JOINs`:

```
AND p.merchant_no = t.merchant_no 

`merchant_no` varchar(4)  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Merchant Number',
`merchant_no` varchar(4)  CHARACTER SET utf8    COLLATE utf8_bin
    DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Merchant Number',
```

Fixing that may not be the whole solution.

What do you think this means?  `count(t.transaction_id) = 1` ?  It means "count the number of rows (in each `GROUP`) where `t.transaction_id` is `NOT NULL`.  Can there be 2 such rows?  If so, that `=1` will be 'false'.

Ranges with the `BETWEEN` being variables is hard to hard to optimizer.  (Alas, I have no remedy.)

```
ON t.transaction_date
         BETWEEN DATE_SUB(p.purchasing_date, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
             AND DATE_ADD(p.purchasing_date, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

But, we can probably get rid of the `GROUP BY` by changing the `LEFT JOIN` into

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1
           FROM transaction_log t 
           WHERE  t.transaction_date
                     BETWEEN DATE_SUB(p.purchasing_date, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
                         AND DATE_ADD(p.purchasing_date, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) 
              AND t.transaction_amount = p.total_amount 
              AND p.merchant_no = t.merchant_no 
              AND t.matched_flag = 'N' 
       )
```

Now, let's make an index for `t`:

```
INDEX(matched_flag, merchant_no, transaction_amount,   -- in any order
      transaction_date)  -- put the range last
```

You have two indexes with `transaction_date` before the end.  *Usually* the utility of an index terminates with a "range".  This makes your indexes not as useful as they could be.

OK, I hit a roadblock.  You need the `EXISTS` twice.  That takes you back to `LEFT JOIN`.  But I don't want to get into the "inflate-deflate" problem.  This where a `JOIN` leads to multiple rows (in a temp table), only to have a `GROUP BY` deflate back to what you started with.  I'll assume the worst, namely that there can be multiple transactions in the 4 minute period for some receipts.

```
    SELECT  purchasing_receipt_id,
            min_tid,
            IF(min_tid IS NULL, 'U', 'A')
        FROM (
            SELECT p.purchasing_receipt_id,
                   ( SELECT min(t.transaction_id)
                       FROM transaction_log t  
                       WHERE  t.transaction_amount = p.total_amount
                         AND  t.merchant_no = p.merchant_no
                         AND  t.matched_flag = 'N'
                         AND  t.transaction_date
                                 BETWEEN p.purchasing_date - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE 
                                     AND p.purchasing_date + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
                   )   AS min_tid
            WHERE  p.processing_id = 783
             ) AS x ;
```

(I don't want to ask what this is about: `AUTO_INCREMENT=2019121320000000015` .)

Comment: So, it mean that now i will create an index INDEX(matched_flag, merchant_no, transaction_amount,   -- in any order
      transaction_date) and try with new query( the final one)

Comment: Yes.  That's a 4-column "composite" index (where the order of the first 3 columns in not critical).

Comment: i've indexed like this and it improve a lot
INDEX(transaction_amount, matched_flag, merchant_no, transaction_date).
I jut have a question:
Why when i create index in diferent order, like matched_flag or merchant_no at the first column, the excution time is very long(Over 2 hour). But if transaction amount is the first column, it only take 4 second to excute.

Comment: @Long - The order of the columns in the `INDEX` is important.  Start with the columns tested with `=`.  More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql